# Unable to insert Time only field into MySQL database using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, time

I seem to be experiencing great difficulty working with Time only fields in Laravel. Nothing I seem to do will allow me to save the entry into the database and has now become frustrating.

I have setup my database schema as such:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create( 'campaigns', function( Blueprint $table ) {
            $table->increments('Id');
            $table->string( 'Name' )->unique();
            $table->integer( 'SupplierId' );
            $table->boolean( 'Active' );
            $table->boolean( 'UseCustomTargetGroup' );
            $table->text( 'CustomGroupList' )->nullable();
            $table->integer( 'SiteGroupId' )->nullable();
            $table->text( 'ExclusionList' )->nullable();
            $table->boolean( 'StartImmediately' );
            $table->dateTime( 'StartTime' )->nullable();
            $table->boolean( 'NeverEnds' );
            $table->datetime( 'EndTime' )->nullable();
            $table->boolean( 'IntervalScheduling' );
            $table->time( 'Interval_1_StartTime' )->nullable();
            $table->time( 'Interval_1_EndTime' )->nullable();
            $table->time( 'Interval_2_StartTime' )->nullable();
            $table->time( 'Interval_2_EndTime' )->nullable();
            $table->time( 'Interval_3_StartTime' )->nullable();
            $table->time( 'Interval_3_EndTime' )->nullable();
            $table->boolean( 'NotificationOnStart' );
            $table->boolean( 'NotificationOnEnd' );
            $table->string( 'Priority' );
            $table->text( 'Recipients' )->nullable();
            $table->integer( 'CreatedBy' );
            $table->integer( 'UpdatedBy' )->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I have set my timezone accordingly in my `app.php`:

```
'timezone' => 'Australia/Adelaide'
```

However, when I send the entry from my AngularJS application it looks like this (when outputting it to console):

```
Interval_1_StartTime: Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0930 (Australian Central Daylight Time)
```

And in Laravel (when I capture `$request->Interval_1_StartTime`), I get returned both a different time that what I posted and an error stating the format is invalid.

```
data: "1969-12-31T14:30:00.000Z"
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect time value: '1969-12-31T14:30:00.000Z' for column 'Interval_1_StartTime' at row 1
```

I have tried using `Carbon::parse`, I have tried using `$cast` to cast the value into specific format, I have even tried using `$dates` to try and convert the value into a proper date.  I have also tried formatting the value into a specific time format `.format('H:m:s')`

Nothing seems to work

Comment: can you update your post with the `create table` statement for the table, please?

Comment: I have updated my post to show the full table creation

Comment: I see.  I actually was interested in what _MySQL_ itself thought the table create was.  Maybe something is wrong with the field type for `Interval_1_StartTime`.  Is it indeed of fieldtype `time`?  Anyway, and i guess you've noticed this, if you subtract 9.5 hours from `Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0930` you get `1969-12-31T14:30:00.000Z` _**UTC Time, ie. +0000**_.

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: I had no luck.  The two wouldn't play nicely (`uib-timepicker` and `MySQL`), so I bit the bullet and reverted my table to use `datetime` instead.  Haven't had an issue since.

Answer (score 0):

> $table->time( 'Interval_1_StartTime' )->nullable();

Allow only format (hh:mm:ss) if you want understand about this type please go to this link [The TIME Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html). If you want insert this type "Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0930" is allow type string you can change your database schema to

> $table->string( 'Interval_1_StartTime' )->nullable();

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I have already referred to that documentation.  As I mentioned above, I have already tried formatting my time object to use `H:m:s`.  I don't want to insert the full date, just the time only.

Answer (score 0):

[This post on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sqlstate22007-invalid-datetime-format-1292-incorrect-datetime-value-0730pm-for-column-departure-time-at-row?page=1#best-reply-386785) says that it's not a Laravel issue...it's a php issue.  He suggests doing it this way:

```
'departure_time' => date("H:i:s", strtotime(request('departureTime')));
```

which interpolated to your case might be:

```
// use $time_to_insert as the value to insert
// assign value posted from angular to $time_posted_from_angular

$time_to_insert = date("H:i:s", strtotime( $time_posted_from_angular ));
```